# After update IBM Mobilefirst in Eclipse, my application is not working

Tags: eclipse, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I just update the IBM Mobilefirst in Eclipse. And I keep getting the cordova error in console.

```
Error in Success callbackId: App494998032 : Error: Unknown event action undefined cordova.js:1576
```

Everything works fine before I update my IBM Mobilefirst in my Eclipse. What should I do? Or do IBM have any ways for me to rollback to previous version of Mobilefirst 7.1?

Thanks.

[image: Error From Browser Console]

Comment: Please provide more information. What is this app? Does it also happen with a new app? What is the build number of your MobileFirst Eclipse plug-in? Can you provide your app so it could be debugged?

Comment: It effect all of my app. Include those app download from
https://developer.ibm.com
Just download any app from the website, compile and run in Android device. Open the app and the error is prompt in console log when the app is start.
In Eclipse Marketplace it just show 7.1.0. And my eclipse is Luna 4.4.2

Comment: @IdanAdar do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can check which build you're using in Eclipse > Help > About > MobileFirst...

I checked for updates in Eclipse and it prompted me to install *IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20151227-1725*.

After installing the update I downloaded one of the samples, imported it to Eclipse and run it. Once previewing the app there were no errors as mentioned in the question.

I suggest that you will check for updates and try again.

---

Comment: Preview and IOS will not throw any error. But for Android it will give me that error.

Comment: and my version is   IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20151227-1725

Comment: This is not happening to me in Android either. Which sample application are you testing this with?

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/adapter-based-authentication-hybrid-applications/

Comment: I downloaded that sample, added the android environment, built it and deployed both the app and the adapter. Opened the console and previewed android. Working with no error.

Comment: Delete the wlBuildResources folder and try again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582419/worklight-build-error-failed-initializing-clientprojectbuilder

Comment: I see this same issue on my real Android device after upgrading my android project to MobileFirst 7.1

Answer (score 0):

See my answer over here...  I had the same issue and fixed it by examining my config.xml file and making sure it had all the required MobileFirst plugins defined.

[Does wlcommoninit get called when the app is reloaded using WL.Client.reloadApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500903/does-wlcommoninit-get-called-when-the-app-is-reloaded-using-wl-client-reloadapp/35416143#35416143)